# Svelte component used conditionally not reacting to prop update

Tags: typescript, svelte

While learning Svelte, I've come across behaviour which isn't mentioned in the documentation.

I've built a tree-view component - actually a series of components. At the bottom of this hierarchy is a component which uses a prop named `shouldShowVersions`. I pass this down through the component hierarchy, but the penultimate component wraps the final component in an `{#if ...}` statement, and it appears that updates to `shouldShowVersions` never make it through this condition.

The penultimate component in the stack contains...

```
{#if isLeaf}
  <Checkbox
    checked={isChecked}
    labelText={treeNode.text}
    on:check={onCheckChanged} />
  {#if hasSingleResource}
    <VersionHistory {shouldShowVersions} versions={treeNode.data[0].resourceVersions} />    << This is the component in question
  {/if}
{:else}
  [...]
{/if}
```

The final component in the stack contains...

```
export let shouldShowVersions: boolean = false;

$: console.log(`VersionHistory: ${shouldShowVersions}`);
```

The above text is never logged - *so long as `VersionHistory` is wrapped inside those `{#if ...}` statements*. If I move `VersionHistory` outside of the conditions then I see the logged text each time `shouldShowVersions` is updated.

Can anyone explain why, and what I need to do in order to have `VersionHistory` react to changes in `shouldShowVersions`?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example from scratch? [This should work](https://svelte.dev/repl/fa971d28341c405fa8242baa443ecbf2?version=4.2.3).

Comment: If you expect this to log anything while the conditions are false, your expectation is wrong.

Comment: @H.B. The `{#if ... }` condition is satisfied, so yes, I expect it to log when `shouldShowVersions` is both true and false. The `VersionHistory` component _is_ displayed but the value of `shouldShowVersions` never updates, even though an updated value is being passed down the component stack (and is being logged in each component).

Comment: Possibly a bug, but a minimal reproduction is required in any case.

Comment: Hmm...  I've built a [minimal reproduction](https://svelte.dev/repl/a678fc4c90e243f5bca08b13389b58bf?version=4.2.3) but ...  it works.

Comment: Then it's not a reproduction, unfortunately 